# How to change the document name via UNO?

Tags: java, libreoffice, uno

I use UNO from Java to control LibreOffice (5.3).
How do I change the document name displayed in the window title bar?

So far I tried to use [`XDocumentProperties`](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/XDocumentProperties.html), but it only sets the title in the document's embedded properties and not in the window title:

```
// Sets only meta data, not the window title.
XDocumentPropertiesSupplier xDocumentPropertiesSupplier = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDocumentPropertiesSupplier.class, openedDocument);
XDocumentProperties xDocumentProperties = xDocumentPropertiesSupplier.getDocumentProperties();
xDocumentProperties.setTitle(retrievedFile.name);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Some sample code and a statement about how you plan to use this would help.  For example, does the code stream documents as in the link in my answer?  Also, indicate what you have tried so far and links to any documentation you researched.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: Please add a comment explaining how to improve the question.

Comment: @JimK Thank you! I tried to improve my question like you explained.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, simply call `storeAsURL` from [XStorable](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XStorable.html).

However, for special cases such as streaming, you may want to use [XDocumentProperties](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/XDocumentProperties.html).  Call `setTitle()` as in the following C++ code from https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=70156.

```
Reference<XModel> xModel(xComponent, UNO_QUERY);
Reference<XTitle> xTitle(xModel, UNO_QUERY);
xTitle->setTitle(constOUString("Title"));
```

**EDIT**:

Here is the [XTitle](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XTitle.html) code from your rejected edit.

```
XTitle xTitle = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTitle.class, xComponent /* e.g. from xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(...) */);
xTitle.setTitle("Title");
```

Note: As the reviewers wrote, this should have been added in comments or a separate answer, not an edit.  It is almost never a good idea to edit someone else's code on this site.  However, it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of those special cases. That aside, though: XDocument properties only sets the meta-data title. It doesn't affect the title displayed in the title bar.

Comment: Using `XTitle` works, but the code from the forum is slightly wrong. You don't need to go through `XModel`.

Comment: @Adeveloper: OK, I edited the answer to incorporate your code.